# In Eve, what is the difference between inserting a document into a collection using the http method POST and using the mongo shell?

Tags: python, eve

**Background Information**

The answer to my previous question ([In Eve, how can you make a sub-resource of a collection and keep the parent collections endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26166344/4103361)) was to use the multiple endpoints, one datasource feature of Eve. In the IRC channel, I was speaking with cuibonobo, and she was able to get this working by changing the game_id to be an objectid instead of a string, as shown here:

http://gist.github.com/uunsamp/d969116367181bb30731

I however didn't get this working, and as you can see from the conversation, I was putting documents into the collection differently:

> 14:59 < cuibonobo> no. it's just that since your previous settings file saved the game id as a string, the lookup won't work
>
> 15:00 < cuibonobo> it will only work on documents where game_id has been saved as an ObjectId
>
> 15:01 < cuibonobo> the way Eve currently works, if you set the type to 'objectid', it will convert the string to a Mongo ObjectId before saving it in the database. but that conversion doesn't happen with strings
>
> 15:02 < znn> i haven't been using eve for storing objects
>
> 15:02 < znn> i've been using the mongo shell interface for inserting items
>
> 15:03 < cuibonobo> oh. hmm. that might complicate things. Eve does type conversions and other stuff before inserting documents.
>
> 15:04 < cuibonobo> so inserting stuff directly into mongo generally isn't recommended

**Question**
Which leads me to stackoverflow :)

What is the difference between inserting a document into a collection using the http method POST and using the mongo shell? Will users eventually be able to use either method of document insertion?

**Extra information**

*I was looking through http://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/eve/methods/post.py before asking this question, but this could take awhile to understand, much longer than just asking someone who maybe is more familiar with the code than myself.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is that Eve is adding a few meta fields `etag`, `updated`, `created` along with every stored document. If you want to store documents locally (not going through HTTP) you can use `post_internal`:

```
Intended for internal post calls, this method is not rate limited,
authentication is not checked and pre-request events are not raised.
Adds one or more documents to a resource. Each document is validated
against the domain schema. If validation passes the document is inserted
and ID_FIELD, LAST_UPDATED and DATE_CREATED along with a link to the
document are returned. If validation fails, a list of validation issues
is returned.
```

Usage [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319716/using-eves-db-layer-without-http/25493169#25493169):

```
from run import app
from eve.methods.post import post_internal

payload = {
    "firstname": "Ray",
    "lastname": "LaMontagne",
    "role": ["contributor"]
}

with app.test_request_context():
    x = post_internal('people', payload)
    print(x)
```

Documents inserted with `post_internal` are subject to the same validation and will be stored like they were by API clients via HTTP. In 0.5-dev (not released yet) PATCH, PUT and DELETE internal methods have been added too.