# Python eve sub-resource / custom query

Tags: python, eve

I am having two resources,

Users resource:

```
users = {
  'schema': {
    'username': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True
    },
    'interests': {
        'type': 'list'
    }
  }
}
```

Example,

```
{"username": "Yogi", "interests":["Sports", "News"]}
```

Events resource:

```
events = {
  'schema': {
    'name': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
    },
    'categories': {
        'type': 'list',
        'required': True,
        'minlength':1
    }
  }
}
```

Example,

```
{"name": "IPLT20", "categories": ["Sports"]}
```

Is there a way in Python Eve to query all events matching the interest of the user.

One way is to construct query like below,

```
/events?where={"$or":[{"categories":"Sports"},{"categories":"News"}]}
```

for this we'll have do a GET of user and using that information we'll have to construct the above query.

Is it possible in Python Eve to have a (one step) query something like,

```
/users/<userid>/events
```

or

```
/events?for=<userid>
```

Comment: for the schema users, interests is a list of what data-type? Similarly, I think the schema users is wrong as you have to specify list of data-type for categories.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#sub-resources) suggests that although it is possible, `where` styled query is preferred/recommended

Answer (score 0):

events should be something like:

```
events = {
    'url': 'users/<regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}":user_id>/events',
    'schema': {
        'user_id': {
            'type': 'objectid',
            'data_relation': {
                'resource': 'queues',
                'field': '_id',
                'embeddable': True
            },
        },
        'name': {
            'type': 'string',
            'required': True,
        },
        'categories': {
            'type': 'list',
            'required': True,
            'minlength': 1
        }
    }
}
```

But this will make you work with events only through `users/<regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}":user_id>/events` link. If you want to keep `/events` endpoint as well use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166344/in-eve-how-can-you-make-a-sub-resource-of-a-collection-and-keep-the-parent-coll) approach